# HTML Video without streaming

Tags: html, video-streaming

Is there a way to have looping videos on HTML page where it doesn't stream off the source?

I have an HTML page with a video tag. The source is a SharePoint library. The videos run smoothly and as expected, but  I'm looking for a way where it doesn't burden the SP server for each time it plays the next video.

We're going to use the page as digital signage, but there will many screens that play it. Is is possible to maybe, store the content on the machine after the page loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to solve this.  Probably the best way is to utilize a Service Worker.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API

This allows your code to act as a proxy of sorts, where you are in direct control of the caching.  The benefit here is that your application can even work offline, which is beneficial for when your SharePoint server is doing it's 3:35 PM on-a-Tuesday crash-and-burn routine.  :-)

An alternative way to solve this problem is to use the Fetch API and get the entire video, and use a Blob URL for the video tag.  This is a bit wonkier than the Service Worker route, so I don't recommend it.